# Delayed processing of recurring monthly membership using PayPal

Tags: civimember, payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions

We use PayPal to process payments for memberships which allow our users special access to our public website.  We recently started a monthly membership with auto-renew, and there seems to be a problem:

PayPal informs me that they process new recurring payment profiles in batches, often a considerable time after the profile has been created.  This means that our new members do not get immediate access to our website, and also the Civi confirmation page that should come after payment, is not delivered to their web browser.

PayPal support has looked at the API log, and said that if I added the following variables, then the first payment would be processed immediately:

1) Specify the variable “Initial Amount”: INITAMT.

2) Specify the "profile start date" one month later: PROFILESTARTDATE

I don't think I should go in and mess with the payment processor api code myself.  Has anyone else encountered this issue, or have ideas on a workaround?

PayPal Payments Pro // CiviCRM 4.6.10 // Drupal 7.39

Comment: I've seen the same experience and it's a painpoint for us as folks sign up for membership in hopes they can immediately register for an event with a member discount. I'm not aware of a work-around, and would suggest logging a bug in the Issue Tracker: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19031?jql=project%20%3D%20CRM (unless someone tells us it's not a bug)